# Export doesn't work for households

Tags: contacts, export, households

I try to export contacts with the option "Merge Household Members into their Households".

As export fields I choose Household → Head of Household is → displayname

But in the export file, this field is empty for all households.

When I export households without the merge-option, the field is filled correctly.

My civicrm version is 4.7.19